# How to automate an report process with python?

Tags: python, html, excel, automation

Every day, I have to create a performance report within one hour. While I cannot change the entire process, my goal is to automate the tedious task of copying and pasting data from other sources into Excel. To streamline this process, we have a dedicated desktop that extracts data every 30 minutes. Here's how I currently handle it: I open the "html" file containing the data, copy all the information, and paste it into worksheet 1 of my Excel file. Additionally, I copy another set of "html" data and paste it into worksheet 2 of the same Excel file.

To make this process more efficient, I need to develop a script that can automatically perform these tasks.

I have attempted to use VBA code, but unfortunately, I haven't been successful because my data is stored in an HTML file. I'm not familiar with how to begin using Python, but I would greatly appreciate a beginner's guide to get me started.

Comment: How much knowledge do you have in Programming/Python and what have you atempted so far?

Comment: It would also help to have an example webpage you want to scrape.

Comment: It's a very raw file, only the header and the table.

Comment: I don't know a lot about python, actually a beginner but i can do some copy and paste code.

Answer (score 0):

So to automate the copy, paste task you can use pandas and openpyxl.

Here is an example of code you can use/edit as per your requirement:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook

df1 = pd.read_html('your_html_file.html')[0]

df2 = pd.read_html('your_html_file.html')[0]

workbook = Workbook()

worksheet1 = workbook.active
worksheet1.title = 'Worksheet 1'
for row in dataframe_to_rows(df1, index=False, header=True):
    worksheet1.append(row)

worksheet2 = workbook.create_sheet(title='Worksheet 2')
for row in dataframe_to_rows(df2, index=False, header=True):
    worksheet2.append(row)

workbook.save('your_excel_file.xlsx')
```